# Link list add,delete and print imlementation

Tags: c++, list, linked-list

The code bellow inserts nodes correctly but 
I have a problem that when try to print the list the program unfortunately stop working.
The error message is : your project has stopped working. 
This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
typedef struct st {
    string data;
    int ISBN;
    string Title;
    string Author;
    int publishedyear;
    bool borrow;
    st* next;
} NODE;

NODE* add(NODE* head, int isbn)
{
    NODE *p1, *p2;
    NODE* n;
    n = new NODE;
    n->ISBN = isbn;
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = n;
        return head;
    }
    if (n->ISBN < head->ISBN) {
        n->next = head;
        head = n;
        return head;
    }
    p1 = p2 = head;
    while (p2 != NULL) {
        if (n->ISBN < p2->ISBN) {
            n->next = p2;
            p1->next = n;
            return head;
        }
        else {
            p1 = p2;
            p2 = p2->next;
        }
    }
    n->next = p2;
    p1->next = n;
    return head;
}

void print(NODE* head)
{
    NODE* p;
    p = head;
    if (head == NULL) {
        cout << "empty list" << endl;
    }

    while (p != NULL) {
        cout << "Book ISBN Is : " << p->ISBN << endl;
        p = p->next;
    }
}
void main()
{

    // cout << "hi";
    NODE* head;
    head = NULL;
    string op;
    int isbn;
    cout << "Enter the opertion in the following format : op , ISBN" << endl;
    while (1) {
        cin >> op;
        if (op == "add") {
            cin >> isbn;
            if (op == "add") {
                head = add(head, isbn);
                cout << "book with thie ISBN code " << isbn << " is added successfuly."
                     << endl;
            }
        }
        else if (op == "print") {
            print(head);
        }
        else {
            cout << "Enter vaild operation! ." << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

any suggestions ?

Comment: Olaf moves at light speed.

Comment: This is C++, not C. But you use C-coding **style** which is a bad practice in C++ and specifically for this application.

Comment: So . how to fix the problem ?

Comment: Crashes make debugging easy. Run program in the debugger that almost certainly came with your development environment an inspect the program state when the debugger halts because of the crash. If you can't figure out the problem from that, add the state to the question.

Comment: Read [ask] and follow it. As @user4581301 wrote: use the debugger to find out more. Also format & indent your code properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was pointed out, but... I feel awfully unsatisfied by the state of your code, so allow me to give you a few tips.

*Note: unless the point is to build a list, do reuse the existing standard containers (`vector`, in particular) and algorithms (`sort`) rather than building your own.*

---

Let's start with the basics, this is the year 2016 you should have access to C++11 by now.

C++11 allows to initialize data-members straight at the point of declaration, and I recommend that you do it for all built-in types (integrals, booleans, floating points and pointers) since by default they otherwise contain garbage which is puzzling.

```
struct Node {
    std::string data;
    int ISBN = 0;
    std::string title;
    std::string author;
    int publishedyear = 0;
    bool borrow = false;
    Node* next = nullptr;
};
```

Note that this alone solves your bug. And it also avoids forgetting it the next time.

---

Secondly, the `add` method should NOT be responsible for creating a node. This is mixing concerns, and it also leaves most of the node with default values and no way to access it without looking for it by its ISBN.

There's also a point that the `add` method does not account for: what if the `ISBN` is already in the list?

```
// Adds the new node to the list, maintaining the ordering by ISBN.
//
// Returns the new head of the list, unless an existing node in the list already
// has this ISBN in which case returns `nullptr`.
Node* add(Node* head, Node* node) {
    assert(node != nullptr && "Null argument provided");

    if (head == nullptr) {
        return node;
    }

    if (node->ISBN < head->ISBN) {
        node->next = head;
        return node;
    }

    if (node->ISBN == head->ISBN) {
        return nullptr;
    }

    //  Find "current" such that "current->ISBN" < "node->ISBN" and
    //                           "node->ISBN" <= "current->next->ISBN"
    Node* current = head;
    while (current->next != nullptr && node->ISBN > current->next->ISBN) {
        current = current->next;
    }

    if (node->ISBN == current->next->ISBN) {
        return nullptr;
    }

    node->next = current->next;
    current->next = node;

    return head;
}
```

Note: `assert` requires `#include <cassert>`.

---

Your print method is already pretty good, congratz!

Just two nitpicks:

- if you know that nothing further will be executed, return immediately, don't wait
- don't use `endl`, it both appends an end of line AND flushes the buffer immediately, which leads to performance issues more often than not

```
//  Prints the list, in order.
void print(Node* head) {
    if (head == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "empty list\n";
        return;
    }

    for (Node* p = head; p != nullptr; p = p->next) {
        std::cout << "Book ISBN: " << p->ISBN << "\n";
    }
}
```

---

And finally, the modified `main`.

Note that I expanded the help text a bit, and provided a (clean) `quit` operation.

The main change, however, is dealing without input error. Dealing with output error is left as an exercise to the reader (hint: make them throw).

It would also be a good exercise to properly deal with the allocated memory.

```
int main() {
    std::cout << "Enter one of the following operations when prompted:\n"
                 " - add <isbn>\n"
                 " - print\n"
                 " - quit\n";

    Node* head = nullptr;

    while (1) {
        std::cout << "> ";

        std::string op;
        if (!(std::cin >> op)) {
            std::cerr << "An error occurred reading the operation, sorry\n";
            break;
        }

        if (op == "quit") {
            std::cout << "See you later!\n";
            break;
        }

        if (op == "print") {
            print(head);
            continue;
        }

        if (op == "add") {
            int isbn = 0;
            if (!(std::cin >> isbn)) {
                std::cout << "Please provide a correct ISBN!\n";
                continue;
            }

            Node* node = new Node();
            node->ISBN = isbn;

            Node* h = add(head, node);
            if (h == nullptr) {
                std::cout << "This ISBN was already provided!\n";
                delete node;
                continue;
            }

            head = h;
            continue;
        }

        std::cout << "Please enter a valid operation!\n";
    }

    // Deal with allocated memory ;)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`st::next` is never set to `NULL`. This makes testing `p!=NULL` in `print` somewhat problematic.

Solution: NULL `next` when the node is the tail node.